# Integrate ingress nginx with spring gateway

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes

I have a solution that use nginx with ingress and spring gateway on minikube. I have tested a request to the gateway using the ingress, but the request does not get to the gateway, even the actuator endpoint of the gateway does not reveice the request.

Configuration of the ingress and use the command `minikube addons enable ingress`on minikube

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    #- host: "microservices-cluster.info"
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: gateway-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

gateway

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: gateway-service
  labels:
    app: gateway-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: gateway-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: gateway-service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: gateway-service
          image: jdavidaraujo/gateway-service:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: POI_SERVICE_URL
              value: http://poi-service
            - name: VEHICLE_SERVICE_URL
              value: http://vehicle-service
            - name: VEHICLE_POSTION_SEARCH_SERVICE_URL
              value: http://vehicle-position-search-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: gateway-service
  labels:
    app: gateway-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: gateway-service
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
```

Spring Gateway

```
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway-service
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: poi-route
          uri: ${POI_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8082}/v1/pois
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/pois/**
        - id: vehicle-route
          uri: ${VEHICLE_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8081}/v1/veiculos
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/veiculos/**
        - id: vehicle-route
          uri: ${VEHICLE_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8081}/v1/posicoes
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/posicoes/**
        - id: vehicle-position-search-route
          uri: ${VEHICLE_POSTION_SEARCH_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8080}/v1/veiculos-poi
          predicates:
            - Path=/v1/veiculos-poi/**
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

poi-service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: poi-service
  labels:
    app: poi-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: poi-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: poi-service
    spec:
    #  serviceAccountName: spring-cloud-kubernetes
      containers:
        - name: poi-service
          image: jdavidaraujo/vehicle-position-solution_poi-service:latest
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
              value: "jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/tb_veiculo"
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
              value: "postgres"
            - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
              value: "postgres"
            - name: SPRING_REDIS_HOST
              value: "redis"
            - name: SPRING_REDIS_PORT
              value: "6379"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: poi-service
  labels:
    app: poi-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: poi-service
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8082
      targetPort: 8080
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: poi-service
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    name: poi-service
  minReplicas: 2
  maxReplicas: 4
  metrics:
    - type: Resource
      resource:
        name: cpu
        target:
          type: Utilization
          averageUtilization: 50
```